# Помогите расставить запятые, пожалуйста

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Оказалось он очень умный и добрый* - тут обособляется "оказалось"?

*Вообще-то, я артист, необразованный ты гремлин...* - тут обособляется "ты"?

*Мама просила не надоедать ей пока она на работе!* - требуется ли запятая после "ей"?

Comment: Отвечу комментарием, потому что полноценный ответ надо обосновывать правилами. **Оказалось, он очень умный и добрый.** // **Вообще-то, я артист, необразованный ты гремлин...** // **Мама просила не надоедать ей, пока она на работе!**

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Марианна, на сайте принято благодарить участников за полезные вопросы и ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также принимать один из ответов галочкой как наиболее понравившийся и решивший проблему.

Answer (score 1):

1. *Оказалось, (что) он очень умный и добрый.*

Пропущено "что", запятая перед придаточным предложением **нужна.**

2. Не надо никакой запятой! Обращения там нету.
3. Придаточное "пока..." надо отделить запятой.